# project.vim reports "is not a valid directory" when refreshing or creating a project

Tags: windows, vim, plugins

I'm using project.vim with VIm to manage large code bases with deep directory structures.

When I switch to another one or create (\C) a new one and do a refresh (\R) project.vim starts displaying messages through the whole process for different directories:

```
<dir_name> is not a valid directory. [O]K:
```

I have to press Enter all the time, although the directories exist. I took a look at the code and it checks if the path is a directory. They are.
Maybe there is a fix for this. The directories are under Perforce management, so everything is read-only.

I have to stay at the keyboard and keep pressing Enter for it to go to next directories... For large code bases this is takes a long time.

I contacted the author some time ago, but there was no response.

Did anyone encounter this before?
Could it be the it is bothered by the read-only-ness?
Is there a fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin uses `glob()` for some of those directory checks, which is affected by the `'wildignore'` setting. Try

```
:set wildignore=
```

If that fixes the problem (and you have at least Vim version 7.2.51), you can modify the plugin's code to use `glob(..., 1)` instead.

Comment: I have wildignore set to empty, but it still doesn't stop showing those messages. I've also added 1 as parameter to all glob occurences in the source code, and still no luck. Also restarted VIm, of course.

Comment: Could it be that the paths contain spaces? A solution woud be to remove the confirm calls from the code, as they are just notification...

Comment: I doubt so. Is `glob()` returning something valid, and `isdirectory()` chokes, or does the glob already fail and return nothing?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with (debugging) VImscript... How can I check that?

Comment: Just `:echo glob('<dirname>')` (with the actual value), and then try the same wrapped in `isdirectory(...)`.

Comment: It looks like there were non-existing directories due to me changing branches with small differences. That is why it reported invalid directories. I used to do a full recursive refresh (\R) when I changed branches and then is when it noticed the differences. If i created a new project (\C), everything runs fine. I will replace confirm with echo in the source code, because I need to change branches without recreating their projects, and just do a refresh when I need to...

Comment: To be more specific, I usually change branches by only changing the paths in the project header and doing a full refresh. I can't wait that long for doing a full recreation. That's why there are minor differences.

Comment: Well, it seems you've found the problem, and it's in your use of the plugin. Fine! Please write an answer, or mark mine (by clicking on the checkmark next to it) to close this question.

Comment: Ok, I will mark it as an aswer. Thanks for your help with it.